# force windows 8 to properly shut down instead of quick shutdown/hibernate (login issue as well)

Tags: windows, windows-8, shutdown, hibernate, password-recovery

So I'm working on some laptops for an uncle of mine and he's got two, few year old laptops that have passwords that were forgotten. This SHOULD be a fairly straight forward process with just loading up OPHcrack or a similar program. Unfortunately, because Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided in windows 8 to make shut down not actually shut down, and instead hibernate. All of the normal utilities I would use to bypass or create a new admin account to get into the computer to reset lost passwords won't work. Since the hard drive is practically locked when it's in this state (hibernation).

The major problem now is though, to properly shut it down, I need to get into windows to disable this. Well, you kind of need the password for that. Which is the entire reason I'm trying to rest it in the first place, lol. Any help is appreciated here, I've tried a few dozen things but I've been trying them with such frequency I'm not sure myself what I have and have not tried.

Comment: Can you get into BIOS? Is the hard drive write-protected (meaning you can't modify its contents) while in hibernation?

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς the hard drive shouldn't be write protected, not from what I can see within the bios. Windows 8 just freaking does this, it's annoying and I've never ran into this issue before. Since windows 8 really didn't last all that long (at least in my memory lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it would be simple to achieve; You need boot into a disk that is different from the laptop's disk and make sure the two disks are connected to the same computer, then open regedit and load the laptop's registry as hive to change the value `HibernateEnabled` located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power`, change it from 1 to 0, and save your changes. Then you can find your way by yourself from here.

Since it's a laptop, it might not be possible to safely remove the hard drive, you need a USB stick, make it a rescue media and boot into the USB stick.

First you need to check the laptop's CPU's "bitness"(32 bit or 64 bit, x86 is 32 bit, x86-64 or x64 is 64 bit), you can get this information in the laptop's BIOS; You need an iso image that matches the CPU.

Refer to this:https://www.howtogeek.com/427223/how-to-download-a-windows-10-iso-without-the-media-creation-tool/ to download the ISO image;

You need \sources\boot.wim in the .iso, refer to this:https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/117664-win10xpe-build-your-own-rescue-media.html to create custom Windows PE USB stick;

Refer to this:https://4sysops.com/archives/regedit-as-offline-registry-editor/ to change the registry offline, I had already given you the key and value you need.

Comment: Should the boot drive be windows, or can it be linux? Just as clarification on if it's possible, since I'll still be doing the win10 boot disk

Comment: Did you read my answer? It must be Windows, because only Windows has regedit.exe.